# Sort specific column in descending order and return the row for all the max values of the column, no pandas

Tags: python, csv, sorting

I have a homework problem where we have to sort a specific csv file by column 3 in descending order.  Then we have to return all the rows that have the max value in column 3 and we can't use pandas because we haven't learned how to use them yet.  We have to code it has a function so the professor can call our function into his code and see it play out.

```
def bigRow():
    new_row = []
    with open('assignment2Data.csv', 'rU', newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='^')
        data = [x for x in reader]

    max_thirdcol_val = max([x[2] for x in data])

    for row in data:
        if row[2] == max_thirdcol_val:
            new_row.append(row)

    return new_row
```

It errors out when I submit it because:

```
File "UNITTEST.py", line 21, in test_unit
    assert(bigRow('assignment2Data.csv', 3)==answer or bigRow('assignment2Data.csv', 3)==answer2)
TypeError: bigRow() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

Comment: Your function should have two arguments: one for the filename, and one for the column number. You will then have to use those arguments within the function instead of the hard-coded values.

Comment: so i need to update the function to read

def bigRow('assignment2Data.csv', 3) ?

Comment: No - function arguments are just like variable names. The test will pass in the actual values.

Comment: He's talking about the function header. You defined the function to have zero arguments and you're giving it two arguments in the function call. Have a look at this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-define-functions-in-python-3).

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to cook dinner for my kid and handle this simultaneously. If I'm understanding correctly, I need to have the function say....                                               defbigRow(max_thirdcol_val, row)?

Comment: @PatHanlon No - see my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

The test code is trying to call your function with two arguments (the filename and the column index). So you need to write your function as:

```
def bigRow(filename, column_index):
    with open(filename, 'rU', newline='') as f:
       reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='^')
       data = [x for x in reader]
    # TODO: Complete this function :)
```